# Not A valid month error while subtracting timestamps

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to subtract timestamp values. It gives ORA-01843: NOT A VALID MONTH error.

Below query runs fine in SQL Devloper,
But while runtime it throws not a valid month error.
I am not able to find out. Can anybody modify this query.

```
Select substr(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(end_time,'DD-MM-YY HH12:MI:SS'))-(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(start_time,'DD-MM-YY HH12:MI:SS')),12,8))as Duration from Job_execution
```

Comment: What are END_TIME and START_TIME columns' datatypes?

Comment: @Littlefoot datatype of start_time and end_time is TIMESTAMP(6)

Answer (score 0):

If those datatypes are `TIMESTAMP`, then why don't you just subtract them?

```
SQL> create table job_execution
  2    (id number,
  3     start_time timestamp(6),
  4     end_time   timestamp(6));

Table created.

SQL> insert into job_execution (id, start_time, end_time) values
  2    (1, to_timestamp('20.11.2019 10:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  3        to_timestamp('25.11.2019 14:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

1 row created.

SQL> select end_time - start_time diff from job_execution where id = 1;

DIFF
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000005 03:30:00.000000

SQL>
```

"Not a valid month" can be result of *timestamp* values stored into `VARCHAR2` columns where you **think** everything is entered correctly, but there are values such as `25.18.2019` (dd.mm.yyyy), as there's no 18th month in any year.

That's why I asked for the datatype.

**[EDIT: how to format the result]**

If you want a "nice" displayed result, then it requires some more typing. For example:

```
SQL> with difference as
  2    (select end_time - start_Time as diff
  3     from job_execution
  4     where id = 1
  5    )
  6  select      extract (day    from diff)          ||' '||
  7         lpad(extract (hour   from diff), 2, '0') ||':'||
  8         lpad(extract (minute from diff), 2, '0') ||':'||
  9         lpad(extract (second from diff), 2, '0') result
 10  from difference;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------
5 03:30:00

SQL>
```

Comment: @actually I want the timestamp difference till seconds, I dont want to include milliseconds in the subtraction. I.e HHMMSS not HHMMSS.#  and if I directly do end_time-start_time then it is not fetching the result  I want.

Comment: I only want HH:MM:SS, so I removed extract (day) from the query. Still the result it shows is like this  :   00:00:2.     What I am expecting is if seconds are in 1 digit then it should add 0 before that single digit and also I dont want milliseconds so that '.' after the second part should not come e.g 00:00:02

Comment: Minutes are MI, not MM.If you don't need days, no problem - remove it. If you have "2" seconds instead of "02", you didn't apply the **LPAD** function as I did.

Comment: Yes. I mean MI, But can you please edit your answer with the context of seconds.

Comment: There's nothing I should do, Atif. It is already there: `lpad(extract (second from diff), 2, '0')`